# Header with both top and bottom aligned content

Tags: css

I've spent some hours trying to get to the bottom of this, maybe someone else can help.

I am trying to build a header with contains a variable height logo on the left-hand side and two block on the right-hand side such that the upper block is top aligned with the logo and the lower block is bottom aligned with the logo.  I want to avoid using TABLE for obvious reasons.  The logo height can be assumed to be longer than the two right hand-side blocks.

My initial attempt was with using the `display:table` etc.. as can be seen here:

```
<header>
    <div class="c1">Logo Here<br />aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa<br />
aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="r1">Upper Block (top align)</div>
        <div class="r2">Lower Block (bottom align)</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header, div { border: solid 1px red; }
div.c1 { background-color: #FDF; }
div.c2 { background-color: #FFD; }
div.r1 { background-color: #DFF; }
div.r2 { background-color: #DFD; }
header {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
header > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.c1 { width: 70%; rowspan:2; }
.c2 { width: 30%; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/ytubnaoc
This fails to push the lower [green] block (and content) to the bottom of the [yellow] container.

I've considered using "[grid layout](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid)" but there is very little browser support for it (IE10+ as of 2015-01-27).

I've also had a play with using "[flex layout](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox)" (two nested layouts - one horizontal, one vertical) but couldn't get this to work either:

```
<header>
    <div class="c1">Logo Here<br />aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="r1">bbbbbbbbb</div>
        <div class="r2">ccccccccc</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header, div { border:solid 1px blue; }
div.c1 { background-color: #FCC; }
div.c2 { background-color: #CFC; }
div.r1 { background-color: #CCF; }
div.r2 { background-color: #FFC; }

header
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
header > div { width: 50%; }
/*header > div > div { height: 50%; }  doesn't work */
.c2
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    /*align-items: stretch;  doesn't work */
}
.r2
{
    text-align:right;
   /* vertical-align:bottom; doesn't work */
   /* align-self:flex-end;  doesn't work */
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/qmz4qcs1

Can anyone advise on how I can do this without resorting to TABLE/TR/TD tags?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position:absolute to bottom align the green div

```css
div {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
div.h1 {
    background-color: #FDF;
}
div.h2 {
    background-color: #FFD;
    position:relative;
}
div.h3 {
    background-color: #DFF;
    text-align:right;
}
div.h4 {
    background-color: #DFD;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
div#header {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
div.h1 {
    width: 70%;
}
div.h2 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="h1">aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa
        <br />aaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="h2">
        <div class="h3">bbbbbbbbb</div>
        <div class="h4">ccccccccc</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/shedali/3sur4ksa/

Comment: Thanks @Franz.  I chose to eliminate abosolute positioning early on as it causes the [green] lower block to encroch on the [blue] upper block if the combined content exceeded that of the dynamic logo [pink] area.  Is there a way to force content not to overrun in this situation?

Comment: Worse case, I should be able to set a `min-height` on the [pink] block. Thansk.